# How to limit the fields returned from Silverlight 4 RIA services query

Tags: silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I'm using RIA services with Silverlight 4 and would like to limit the fields that are returned from the service.  For example:

```
TableA:
  ID
  Field1
  Field2
  Field3

TableB:
  ID
  TableAID (foreign key)
  Field1
  RestrictedField2
```

In my domain service class I have something like this that was generated when I created the service.  I added the includes (which are working fine):

```
<RequiresAuthentication()>
Public Function GetTableA() As IQueryable(Of TableA)
    Return Me.ObjectContext.TableA.Include("TableB")
End Function
```

My question is, how do I get all of the columns from TableA and also get Field1 from TableB without returning the RestrictedField2?  I'm pretty sure this is done through some Linq fanciness, but I'm not quite sure how.

Thanks!
Matt

**Update**

One requirement that I didn't list above.  The column **must** be removed on the server side as the data in RestrictedField1 cannot have any chance of being sent to the client.  Also, I will need to use this field in a different domain service method (protected with RequiresRoleAttribute), so I can expose the information to an administrator.  This requirement means that I don't want to create a different complex type and return that.  I would prefer to continue working with the EF model type.

Comment: I also reposted this question on the Silverlight Forum and received a similar reply to my answer below:  http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/227614/551503.aspx#551503

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some information that I found, the best way to accomplish what I need is to create a view in the database and expose the data I need via EF and RIA Services.  This appears to be the best solution available.

Comment: The view is one way to go, but another would be to simply create a ViewModel class which encapsulates the data you want to return.

Comment: @Nissan Fan:  This doesn't solve my problem as the restricted information would still go through the service to the ViewModel.  Anyone with a HTTP sniffer (Fiddler) could get at the data by looking at that.  Better yet, they could just create their own client proxy and call the service directly.  I need to prevent these types of scenarios.

Comment: Actually, a ViewModel is a concrete class that you define which contains only the information that you want/need.  You will return that from an Invoke method or a Get in RIA as the result of a call from the Silverlight client.

Comment: @Nissan Fan:  Ah, gotcha, I was thinking you were placing the ViewModel on the client side.  What you're proposing isn't a lot different from changing the "model" (i.e. adding the view), so I'd consider that the same type of solution.

Comment: Either a View or a ViewModel will suffice; the ViewModel approach does have the added advantage for you to not have to make changes at the database either now or in the future should the requirements change.

Answer (score 1):

Check this link, I think it may solve your problem without the need of a view model

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/ab7b251a-ded0-487e-97a9-

I appears you can return an anonymous type then convert it to your needed type.